# Jupyter Kernel: Inject HTML

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am currently trying to write a custom jupyter kernel (deriving from kernelbase.Kernel) that is able to place HTML code into the notebook on `do_execute` of my kernel.

I tried

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<h1>Hello HTML</h1>"))
```

with the [EchoKernel Example](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrapperkernels.html#example) but it does nothing. Neither do what I want nor complain.

How to place HTML code into the notebook from a kernel? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can display HTML by sending a `display_data` message over the IOPub channel. From a kernel that is derived from `ipykernel.kernelbase.Kernel` ([documentation](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrapperkernels.html#making-simple-python-wrapper-kernels)), call this code from the `do_execute` method:

```py
self.send_response(self.iopub_socket, 'display_data', {
    'metadata': {},
    'data': {
        'text/html': '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'
    }
})
```

See [these docs](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messaging.html#messages-on-the-iopub-pub-sub-channel) for more details about the messages you can send over the IOPub channel.